# HBSCAN membership probability

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning, dbscan, hdbscan

I'm working on a comparison between clustring algorithms and I want to know how **HDBSCAN** in R calculate the so called the *membership 'probability'* ?

Comment: Hello Skoubani. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Which version of `hdbscan()` are you using? Would you please post the code you used to run `hdbscan()`, including the packages you loaded? Also consider reading [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and if you will be regularly posting to the `r tag`, read the [r tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `dbscan` package, the `hdbscan()` function does some validity checking of the object passed as input, and then calculates a distance matrix to its `k` nearest neighbors using the `dbscan::kNNdist()` function. The value of `k` is set to the argument `minPts` that is passed to the `dbscan()` function less 1.

```
 core_dist <- kNNdist(x, k = minPts - 1)
```

It then uses core distance as the measure of density and calculates membership probabilities using the following algorithm (from the [hdbscan.R](https://rdrr.io/cran/dbscan/src/R/hdbscan.R) source ):

```
  ## Generate membership 'probabilities' using core distance as the measure of density
  prob <- rep(0, length(cl))
  for (cid in sl){
    ccl <- res[[as.character(cid)]]
    max_f <- max(core_dist[which(cl == cid)])
    pr <- (max_f - core_dist[which(cl == cid)])/max_f
    prob[cl == cid] <- pr
  }
```

For each cluster id in the salient clusters object `sl`, the algorithm calculates the maximum core distance, and then builds probabilities by subtracting each element's distance from the maximum distance, dividing the result by the maximum distance to convert it a proportion.

These coverage probabilities are then inserted into the list that is output by the `hdbscan()` function as the `membership_prob` object.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer !